# Laravel Eloquent ManyToMany getLatest

Tags: mysql, laravel

I built up a pivot table containing ids of tables I want to associate. When I have the id of a specific item, I now want to get the latest entry of this item saved in the pivot table. For example:

```
Table 1: Tickets
Table 2: Status
Table 3: Ticket_Status (Pivot)
```

If I add a new entry to the pivot table, I would have something like this:

**Pivot**

**ticketId, statusId**

```
1, 2

1, 3

2, 1
```

Now I want to receive the latest status in the pivot for Ticket `Id` 1 for example, so I expect to receive `statusId` 3 for ticket 1. But how do I do this in Laravel?

Creating the entries for the pivot table works:

```
public function attachDispatchStatus($id) {
    $this->status()->attach($id);
    $this->touch();
}

// set fields on the eloquent object and save to database
// raise event that the incident was created.
public function createDispatch($command) {

    // Get BodyContent from POST Request
    $this->dispatchReference = $command->dispatchReference;
    $this->incidentReference = $command->incidentReference;

    // Create new Dispatch
    $dispatch = Dispatch::create(array(
        'dispatch_reference' => $this->dispatchReference,
        'incident_reference' => $this->incidentReference
    ));
    $dispatchStatus = DispatchStatus::where('status', '=', 'processing')->first();
    $dispatch->attachDispatchStatus($dispatchStatus->id);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);` available in Laravel 5 when editing your tickets ?

This will solve your problem and make your database lighter :)

Check [Larvel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) for some examples on pivot table.

If you don't want to make it like that (because you want to keep an historic of your input), I think you will have to add an dateTime field in your pivot table... Then, just order by date, and you will be fine.

Comment: I see... Yeah.. I need the history to make a status change on a ticket traceable.

Comment: So you must add a updated_at field on your pivot table. Then, things will go easy.

Comment: Jup.. I have that added. But is there a laravel method I can use so the latest entry for a specific id is being retrieved from the pivot?

Comment: @sesc360
Yes, for sure, retrieving latest entry is possible with something like `$ticket->pivot()->latest()->get();`. Notice that you'll need an `pivot()' method on your model ;)

Comment: in what way does pivot() need to be implemented?

Comment: @sesc360 Yes, on your Ticket model, it will be a hasMany method from Ticket to Pivot, like that i guess : `public function pivot() { return $this->hasMany('App\Pivot'); }`. Think that you'll need also a Pivot model for retrieving data (but he will be very simplistic, with no real method inside)

Comment: @sesc360 Also, I'm giving you this solution, but in my mind, an updated_at field on the pivot table should be just what you need. On that, you'll retrieve the last one (with a great `statut->latest()`), but also all the tracability you need ;)